# How to connect from a DO Droplet Ubuntu 18.04 to a DO Managed MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean

I am trying to connect from a Droplet in DO to a managed MySQL 8 database.

In the Droplet, this is MySQL version

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I guess, this is the "mysql-client" I am using from the Droplet.

I created a managed database, and I am able to connect from my local. I whitelisted my ip and the Droplet.

But when I connect through ssh to the droplet, and then try to connect to MySQL, with the same command I used from my computer, I get

> ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it helps someone else, I updated the `mysql` version on the server and I was able to connect.

The problem was that the client version on the server was not able to connect to mysql8.